#  Samsung Galaxy Player comparison

Tags: samsung-galaxy-player

I noticed [3 devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Player#Models) all featuring same Android ver.

What is the most advanced device of these 3? Are their features overlapping each other, or they are three devices that are meant to serve different needs?

- Galaxy Player 4 (YP-G1)
- Galaxy Player 5 (YP-G70)
- Galaxy Player 50 (YP-G50)

Any other versions missing in that page?
I wanna buy the latest and most advanced Android version that has the most features of that device.

Comment: From what I remember the main difference between the models is screen/device size and battery capacities, the version of Android isn't a main difference (specially as Samsung can update these freely without the networks blocking them like they've done with phones). Will see if I can dig some specs up and put a proper answer in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Galaxy Player Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Player) the differences are:

> **Galaxy Player 4 (YP-G1)** The Galaxy Player 4 features a 4" Super Fine LCD.
>   It had a flash internal storage of 8
>   GB or 16 GB that can be expanded with
>   microSD card.
>
> **Galaxy Player 5 (YP-G70)** The Galaxy Player 5 features a 5" TFT LCD.
>   It had a flash internal storage of 8
>   GB or 16 GB that can be expanded with
>   microSD card.
>
> **Galaxy Player 50 (YP-G50)** The YP-G50 model carries a 3.2" LCD TFT
>   instead of the AMOLED which is used by
>   Samsung in most of its phones. The
>   screen has a 240×400 resolution. It
>   has a flash internal storage of 16 GB
>   or 32 GB that can be expanded with a
>   microSD card.

So the main differences are the size and quality of the screen (and the device), and the internal memory capacity.

Essentially the "50" has the smallest, worst quality screen, but (depending which capacity you get) has the most internal memory, the "4" and "5" are larger devices with better quality, larger screens but (potentially) not as much internal memory.

According to another review I found:

> ...4.0 and 5.0 have almost the same specifications... the 4 inch version has a battery
>   capacity of 1200mAh, whereas the 5
>   inch version is 2500mAh

So the "5" has a larger battery which should last longer, though this may be offset slightly by the larger screen, and will also make the device slightly bigger and heavier than the "4". Battery life should be better than equivalent phone models (especially if you switch off wifi when you're not using it), as the phone's wireless radio is one of the largest battery hogs in the device. Full size and weight specs of the devices are in the sidebar on the Wikipedia page.

So it looks like none of the devices are "better" than the others, they all appear to have their own benefits but are aimed at different buyers.

Comment: I now own an iPod Touch, I hate iTunes and decided to move to Android. I will appreciate any other highlights on my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I am confused about these product's name comparisons for international and US distribution.

None of these Galaxy Player models have been released in the US.
I have seen what you refer to as the Galaxy Player 4 & 5 labeled
as Galaxy S Wi-fi 4 & 5 in trade show videos on YouTube as well as Samsung's UK site, e.g. http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/tv-audio-video/mp3-digital-audio/mobile-internet-players/YP-G1CW/XEU/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail.  In mid-May, Samung's US site http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/mp3-players/ had the Galaxy Player 4.0 and 5.0 listed with full specs, price and even reference to Best Buy as an official retailer before yanking down references to the Galaxy Player only a week later.  Very confusing.

I search Google daily for signs that the "Galaxy Player" 4 or 5 has been released in the US.  However, I am uncertain as to which search terms I should use because I have seen what appears to be the same product referred to both as the "Samsung Galaxy Player 4.0" and the "Samsung Galaxy S Wi-fi 4.0".

Does anyone have evidence indicating what Samsung will be calling the "Galaxy Player" 4 or 5 equivalent for the US market?

Comment: They are out in the US and have been for a while. I'm not sure when they came out but I saw one at Best Buy months ago and wanted one ever since and just finally got one a few days ago.